# setCustomValidity "Empty"

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I try setCustomValidity when the input value is Empty, it's working but the problem is the error popup keeps showing the message(when input is in focus)...

```js
function chec() {
 inn = document.getElementById('num');
 if (inn.value == "") {
  inn.setCustomValidity("Empty");
 } else {
  inn.setCustomValidity("");
 }
}
```

```html
<form>
<input type="number" id="num" min="20" max="50" required>
<input type="submit" onclick="chec()">
</form>
```

Comment: remove html error and put the javascript error when user will submit the button and input is empty it will show error

Comment: @sayalok it does`t change anything, it still shows the popup when is on focus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<form>
<input type="number" id="num" min="20" max="50" required oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Empty')" 
   oninput="setCustomValidity('')" />
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

I created a version that works without use of external function. You can eventually separate your functions , but in the end the result will be the same. Let me know if it worked please.